# How to position house? Roblox

Tags: roblox

I have a problem. How do I make a house position like in Adopt Me (I hope you understand)

[image]

I do like this (Example):

[image]

Is there any way to make this easier? I really hope you understand me and help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a model, and set a primarypart for the model. (The primarypart should probably be in the middle) You can also use scripts to move the model with the primary part using model:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(CFrame) Resources for models are:
https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Model